# Яндекс карты помогите установить на сайт

Tags: яндекс-карта-api

Создали сайт о рыбалке, требуется установить яндекс карту , чтоб каждый гость смог установить метку на этой карте, где он был. карта чтоб была интерактивная, так как по всей стране рыбачат. но чтоб эти метки через сутки например исчезали, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Уф..и тут мне не кто не ответил(

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и следуйте им, тогда будет все в порядке, ответят как надо

Answer (score 1):

Для такой задачи надо писать модуль или делать скрипт. Ответ - нет готового решения.